# Using glib and gtk+ to control ftdi device over USB

Tags: c, gtk, glib, uart, ftdi

I am developing a simple application in C with GTK+2.0 GUI, on Linux of course, this application is designed to control a device which is connected over the USB port and is using FTDI driver to emulate RS232 asynchronious protocol over the USB port.

I wanted to create event driven control, like signals in GTK which are used to detect when the button is clicked et cetera. I found glib library for this, I have read in the documentation it seems clear. I know I must use functions like g_io_add_watch() to add event to be detected, that I can define my functions which would be "triggered" by this event and that for example "G_IO_IN" means it will be triggered when there is some output from the device. I just cannot find any usefull examples on the web.

The other thing is, I do not understand how to use GTK+2.0 and glib at once, because both have their own program loops to detect events (gtk_main() for GTK+2.0 and GMainLoop in glib).

I would be greatfull if you share some interesting examples, links, tutorials et cetera. Maybe I need to know more specific vocabulary, because I cannot find anything usefull on the web to solve this problem.
Thanks!

Comment: GTK+ uses glib, so for the GUI stuff you rarely need to use the glib API directly. A notable exception is the `g_signal_connect()` family of functions, for connecting GTK+ signal handlers to your graphical elements (like when clicking a button in your example) since the outdated `gtk_signal_connect()` has been depreciated a long time ago. On the other hand, `gtk_main()` is still the preferred way for starting the main GUI loop.

Comment: yes, I am using `g_signal_connect()` to define GUI events, I'm just not sure how to integrate detection of ftdi driver signals, so it would be possible to use the divice like G_OBJECT in order to create an event with `g_signal_connect()` ?

Comment: Oh I see, unfortunately I cannot help you with the ftdi driver signals (have not enough experience). But for emitting GTK+ signals have a look at the `g_signal_emit_()` family of functions, along with the documentation around them. You can also create, emit and handle your own GTK+ signals (via `marshallers` if I recall correctly).

Comment: I see, so it seems possible to define custom GTK+ signals, I looked up the keyword `marshallers`. Problem isn't solved yet, but thanks, at least I'm not at dead end anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GTK+ uses GLib, and the main loop is not an exception. This means the [GTK+ loop](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk3-General.html) is a [GMainLoop](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html), hence all the GLib functions can be used with it.

Here is a reference to the GTK+ code to [prove this](http://git.gnome.org/browse/gtk+/tree/gtk/gtkmain.c?id=dde714386de730058981c87c807c83c05b5dc7be#n1144).

Comment: I understand. So please tell me, if I reference `#include <gtk/gtk.h>` will I reference (by transition) also glib?
And if I define events by `g_io_add_watch(...)` and later start the `gtk_main()` loop will it wait for those events to occur?

Comment: `#include <gtk/gtk.h>` will pull in `#include <glib.h>` and `#include <glib-object.h>`. This is not documented so I personally include them explicitely in my projects. For the second question the answer is "yes, you can use `g_io_add_watch()`" and "no, the main cycle will not wait". `g_io_add_watch()` does not pause the cycle but it devises a callback call.